# Can anyone explain why content won't clear?

Tags: css

[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/6k3J2/)

I know I could easily fix this by adding `display:block` to the `post-title` class however I was wondering what am I doing wrong and why clearfix doesn't work.

I grabbed the [clearfix code](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) from css-tricks, if I understood everything right it should be applied to the parent element.

I want to clear the space before the 'h2', a dirty `<br />` hack it works but I was wondering how I could do it with the code provided.

Comment: `.post-title { clear:right; }` [That's](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/6k3J2/2/) the point.

Comment: I think you answered your own question: `I understood everything right it should be applied to the parent element.` but you are defining the fix to the `.group` (which is already the parent element.  @Ted is correct by defining it to `.permalink`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you want:

```
.permalink a {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

.icon-time {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

/* http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/ */
.permalink:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

And the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6k3J2/1/)

Comment: I've tried adding both the 'permalink' and the 'group' classes to the div before and it wasn't working. You've applied 'inline-block' to .permalink a and not just .permalink. That's what did the trick for me, now it's more clear, thanks.